# Using MonoTouch.Dialog's ImageElement as read-only

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, monotouch.dialog

I would like to use MonoTouch.Dialog framewrok to display some readonly info.
I think I can get along with using labels for all my values and the only problem I have is with an `UIImage`. I would like to show an `UIImage` but prevent the `UIImagePickerController` from being used.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `ImageElement` ?

If so simply create your own `MyImageElement` type that inherits from `ImageElement` and override the `Selected` method to do nothing (or something else). E.g.

```
class MyImageElement : ImageElement {

    public MyImageElement (UIImage image) : base (image)
    {
    }

    public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
    {
    }
}
```